# More complex diamond problem instance. How to make it work with constant fields?

Tags: c++, diamond-problem, class-constants

Let us consider ordinary diamond problem but slightly improved. Now  `class A` have constant fields.

```
struct A {
   const int a;

   A (int _a): a(_a) {}
};

struct B: virtual A {
   const int b;

   B(int _b, int _a): A(_a), b(_b) {}
};

struct C: virtual A {
   const int c;

   C(int _c, int _a): A(_a), c(_c) {}
};

struct D: B, C {
    D(int _a, int _b, int _c): ??? {}
};
```

So, what would be sensible to write instead of question marks? Or maybe it can be solved different way?

Comment: Could you describe (in words) what makes your diamond problem "slightly improved"? I see nothing special in your code.

Comment: @JaMiT So, I want to understand how do I handle the fact that fields are constant. It doesn’t seem that trivial to me. Originally, fields weren’t constant as I remember

Comment: @math-traveler How is this changing the problem?

Comment: @math-traveler What difference does `const` make? With or without it, it's a question of how the base object gets constructed, see [c++ diamond inheritance constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360572/c-diamond-inheritance-constructor) for example.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević I have no idea how I can create instance of class D. What should I write instead of question marks?

Comment: @math-traveler I suspect you are trying to ask how to use initializer lists, but I would consider that a normal part of the diamond problem.

Comment: @JaMiT well, probably, yes.

Comment: You are probably looking for: [c++ virtual inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/c-virtual-inheritance). Again, ordinary diamond problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor may be written as follows:

```
D(int _a, int _b, int _c): A(_a), B(_b, _a), C(_c, _a) {}
```

Because `A` is a virtual base class, the `D` constructor must initialize it despite the fact that it is not a *direct* base class. When an object of most derived type `D` is being constructed, `D::D` will first initialize `A`, and then run the constructors for `B` and `C`. When the `B` and `C` constructors run, they will ignore the virtual base class `A`, since `D` already initialized it.

Comment: Oh, it really works this way? Sounds really awesome. For some reason I have never heard about this effect of virtuality. Thank you